# Bind Items to a DropDownBox in OpenUI5

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I am trying to bind a Value inside of an Array with Objects to a [sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox.html).

My JSON-structure looks like that:

```
{
  "forms": [
    {
      "name": "First Object"
    },
    {
      "name": "Second Object"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I try to **bindItems** to my DropdownBox like that:

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();
oItemTemplate.bindProperty("text", "{/name}");

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

var oDropDown = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("dropDownBox");

oDropDown.bindItems("/forms", oItemTemplate);
```

Unfortunately the Items, i am adding/binding to the Dropdown, are empty.

How to properly bind Items in an Array of Objects to a DropdownBox?
[JSBIN-Example](http://jsbin.com/sagomeqayi/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after a very restfully night :)

This is the working code snippet:

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem();
oItemTemplate.bindProperty("text", "name");

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

var oDropDown = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("dropDownBox");  
oDropDown.bindItems("/forms", oItemTemplate);
```

[JSBIN-Example](http://jsbin.com/guhudovuro/1/edit?html,output)